# How to add web.config file to .NET core 2.1 project? Some referenced dll needs to read value from <appsettings>

Tags: web-config, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, appsettings

I've built a .NET Core 2.1 MVC project which containing appsettings.js as config instead of web.config.

I had to add reference to a dll as a requirement of the project, that referenced dll need config values from web.config file. But the problem is .NET Core 2.1 MVC project doesn't contain a web.config file.

Please help me to find a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create web.config at the root of your project.

When the application is published, the compiler always creates a web.config, if it already exists in your project, it will get your changes and add on publish web.config

Comment: Hi Deivid, Thanks for your reply.